# How to fix AWS EC2 Curl Error 303 See Other

Tags: curl, amazon-ec2, restful-url

I have a java program which hits a uaa url and fetch access token and using that it hits another web service and fetch data.

This program is working in local and tomcat server of local but it is not working in aws ec2 linux instance. I always get

> 303 See Other: ErrorCode: 718GTS

I have tried using curl but same error is coming

There should be json response for the web service

Answer (score 0):

this is possibly a certificate issue.  Check with your org about auth certificate required.  Set up startup script in the instance to install the certificate.